# Spring Aspectj instantiation models in webapp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop, aop

I've a Spring web application and I'm trying to add some aspect to my service objects. The goal is to maintain aspect's state only through a single request scope, and to obtain a reference to aspect instance so I can manage state. I've tried 3 different versions of code, making requests via controller:

1. Same as related code (see below). State is retained through multiple invocations, but the `@Autowired TestAspect aspect` instance is not the same use by AOP framework.
2. Adding `factory-method="aspectOf"` to testAspect bean declaration in beans-context.xml, state is retained as previous case, and the `@Autowired TestAspect aspect` instance is the same used by AOP framework. Although it works, I want aspect's scope to be a single request, while in this case I have an application-scoped singleton.
3. Substituting `@Aspect` with `@Aspect("perthis(participateAroundPointcut())")` I get the following exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean with name 'testAspect' is a singleton, but aspect instantiation model is not singleton`, both with `factory-method="aspectOf"` or without.

How can I get `@Autowired TestAspect aspect` reference to be the same aspect instance used by AOP framework? Is `factory-method="aspectOf"` the only one way? 
And how can i have a request-scoped aspect instead of a singleton? Why am I getting the exception?

Here is my code. 
Service:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestAspect aspect;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestService.class);

    public void method(){
            logger.debug("Executing method");
    }

    public void service(){
        aspect.initialize();
        method();
    }
}
```

Aspect: (without `("perthis(participateAroundPointcut())")`)

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParticipatoryAspect.class);

    private boolean initialized=false;

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.mose.emergencyalert.TestService.method(..))")
    public void participateAroundPointcut(){}

    @Around("participateAroundPointcut()")
    public void participateAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        logger.debug("Pre-execution; Initialized: "+initialized);
        joinPoint.proceed();
        logger.debug("Post-execution");
    }

    public void initialize(){
        this.initialized=true;
        logger.debug("Initialized: "+initialized);
    }
}
```

beans-context.xml (without `factory-method="aspectOf"`):

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="testAspect" class="org.mose.emergencyalert.aop.aspects.TestAspect"/>
```

Comment: The service should not be aware of the aspect, otherwise there is little point in using AOP.

Comment: Of course, you're right, but consider this a trivial example. In a real scenario the aspect would be injected in a third service, not involved in AOP.

Comment: I think perhaps your exact approach needs tweaked. Instead of attempting to inject the aspect into the service, I would inject something (service, component etc.) into both the aspect and the service. This would be shared between them.

Comment: Ok, but what about request scope? I can't inject a request-scoped bean in a singleton aspect. So I switched to a `perthis` scoped aspect but i can't get autowiring works. Here you can find the new code [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478922/spring-injecting-resources-in-per-scoped-perthis-pertarget-aspect]